# Is there a CSS to style-attribute converter?

Tags: html, css

I'm searching for a program or website that does convert html-code and css-code into a single html-sequence.

```
|| CSS
div { color: #eaf; }

|| HTML
<div>Foo</div>
<p>Bar <div>&amp; Spam!</div></p>
```

Should be converted to

```
<div style="color:#eaf;">Foo</div>
<p>Bar <div style="color:#eaf;">&amp; Spam!</div></p>
```

**Why I search for it?**

Because most email-clients do not support `<style></style>` in the email's body.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper syntax would be...

```
<div style="color:#eaf;">Foo</div>
<p>Bar <span style="color:#eaf;">&amp; Spam!</span></p>
```

[Here's a link](http://www.pelagodesign.com/sidecar/emogrifier/) to an online tool.

[Here's another link](http://www.soldesignco.com/dev-csstoinline.php) to an online tool.

I've used both of these in the past with good results.

Answer (score 1):

I found this: http://www.pelagodesign.com/sidecar/emogrifier/

Is that what you're looking for?